# Getting the dropdown list in Dataset to Postman from Netsuite through REST Integration

Tags: dataset, netsuite, netsuite-rest-api

I tried to GET the Dataset from Netsuite to Postman using REST
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGV4p.png)
I got the response but it is getting the Internal IDs for values in dropdown lists instead of the values/labels.

[For example, Here it is showing 51,31,97,B as values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWOUa.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tsPM.png)
How can i get the value/label from the dropdown lists while integrating?

Comment: Please show the page where this 'dataset' is configured. A presume it's a Netsuite page, where this is done